# Is there a predefined method to compute area of a polygon in Nutiteq?

Tags: polygon, area, nutiteq

I ask **IN NUTITEQ**, I know the way to perform this with `GoogleApi` with `computeArea()` but I have not found anything in `Nutiteq sdk/snapshot`.

Thanks in advance.

p.s. I know many methods to compute the area but I want to call something own of `Nutiteq`

**EDIT**:

There are no built-in Method, thanks for the fast answer Jaak, so I researched and found 2 Methods, both of them under WSG84 Projection. I developed a little programm to compare both of them and then I compared to a KML Tool, which computes area of a Polygon.

[how-can-i-measure-area-from-geographic-coordinates](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/711/how-can-i-measure-area-from-geographic-coordinates)

[A-link-to-a-Geographic-Framework](http://geographiclib.sf.net/html/classGeographicLib_1_1PolygonArea.html)

And the [results](http://extension.unh.edu/kmlTools/index.cfm) with a kml tool of University of New Hampshire

`12197.38184`

```
import java.lang.Math.*;
import net.sf.geographiclib.*;

public class ComputeAreaTest {

  private static double[][] moorwiese_coords = {{12.925634f,48.427168f}, 
                                                {12.926825f,48.427217f},                                          
                                                {12.926788f,48.428385f}, 
                                                {12.926069f,48.428374f},
                                                {12.925431f,48.42825f}, 
                                                {12.925624f,48.427192f},                                                 
                                                {12.925634f,48.427168f}};

  protected static double computeArea() {
      double area=0.0;
      double earthRadius = 6378137.0f;

      int size = moorwiese_coords.length;     

      if (size > 2) {
          double[] p1 = new double[2];
          double[] p2 = new double[2];

          for (int i=0; i<size-1; i++) {
              p1 = moorwiese_coords[i];
              p2 = moorwiese_coords[i+1];
              area += Math.toRadians(p2[0] - p1[0]) * (2 +  
              Math.sin(Math.toRadians(p1[1]) ) + Math.sin(Math.toRadians(p2[1])) );
          }

          area = area * earthRadius * earthRadius / 2.0;
      }   

      return area;  
  }

  protected static double computeAreaWithGeographicLib() {

    int size = moorwiese_coords.length;
    PolygonArea p = new PolygonArea(Geodesic.WGS84, false);

    try {

        for (int i=0;i<size;i++) {
            p.AddPoint(moorwiese_coords[i][4], moorwiese_coords[i][0]);
        }   
    }
    catch (Exception e) {}
    PolygonResult r = p.Compute();

    return r.area;        
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {


  double areaGeoLib = computeAreaWithGeographicLib();  

  double area = computeArea();  

      System.out.println("Area: " + (-1)*area + "\nArea(GeoLib): "+areaGeoLib);
  }
}
```

`Output
Area: 12245.282587113787
Area(GeoLib): 12254.95547034964`

I found not very suitable for accurate use ( Yes, under 0.5% Error may be unaccurate for many environments) but useful to learn how to compute the area of a irregular Polygon.

Comment: Nutiteq has no built-in method for this. Like with distance - different methods give different results, depending on accuracy and projection. If you have good method, you can post it here as answer and I can add it to Utils.

Comment: Thanks for the code and answers. Btw, you could add them as Answer (yes, you can answer your own questions) and accept this, so the question is not left open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx, Jaak, I had not seen this freen Symbol to click "Right Answer", now I have seen, I must explicitly. So, an "answer" is in initial post.